# What is the step by step procedure to obtain a ZAV certificate for German Visa?

Tags: schengen, germany

I am an Indian undergraduate student in my 3rd year,I have been accepted for an internship in a German University, I applied for a short term visa (Guest Scientist / Visiting Scholar) after gathering all the required [documents]: (http://www.india.diplo.de/contentblob/4002764/Daten/3548245/guest_scientists.pdf), but I got a call from German Embassy a few days later after applying and they need a ZAV certificate. My Prof. isn’t aware of ZAV.

What do I need to do to get a ZAV certificate from Germany?

Comment: ZAV is a part of the German job agency. For students who want to do an internship they need to approve that the position fits your situation/qualification. There is information in German [here](https://www3.arbeitsagentur.de/web/content/DE/service/Ueberuns/WeitereDienststellen/ZentraleAuslandsundFachvermittlung/JobsundPraktika/JobsundPraktikainDeutschland/alsStudierender/index.htm). I could not find that in English. Your best bet is probably to write an email to them or call them (which might be expensive). Hopefully they speak more English than the average agent at _Arbeitsagentur_ does.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
I have emailed my Prof. but haven't gotten any response,
Anyway,I would be highly thankful to you  If you could tell me the documents that I'll need to provide so that ZAV certificate gets approved by the Arbeitsagentur, please let me know as soon as possible.
Thanks again for your time. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Is the professor in your local university in India, or is it the one in Germany? You should contact the administration in the German university that you applied to. They are the ones offering the position, so they should also be the ones talking to Arbeitsagentur to justify it with ZAV I guess. I couldn't find anything about doing that yourself, and I unfortunately know nothing about that process. You will need to dig. Asking the embassy for a starting point might also be a good idea. If they actually called you to clarify then they might also give more information if you ask.

Comment: The question is off-topic because Travel is not for living/working/studying inside a country, you need to ask the question in expatriates.se. For your current question, refer your professor to this [pdf](https://www3.arbeitsagentur.de/web/wcm/idc/groups/public/documents/webdatei/mdaw/mdc4/~edisp/l6019022dstbai381815.pdf) which explains in detail. For internship (max 12 months) you need at least 4 semester experience. The prof needs to fill out the document, create an internship plan and provide a print of the anabin database. You give a certificate of enrollment and a passport copy.

Comment: @simbabque I am in contact with my professor in Germany. I will try to search the documents and ask the embassy too. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Thorsten S. Thanks for pdf link, I will surely refer this to my Prof. but I wanted to ask you about the document you mentioned. "The prof needs to fill out the document". May I know which document are you talking about and where can I find it so that I may be able to send it to my Prof. with the link you mentioned, also is [this](http://culturalvistas.org/cms/assets/uploads/2016/06/1-ZAV_Certificate-of-Enrollment_blank.pdf) the correct Certificate of Enrollment that I need to fill and get it stamped from my home university in India ?
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

The ZAV is a special unit of the employement agency of Germany. For internships they are needed to give an approval: The most important question is whether it is a compulsory or voluntary internship? The former must be documented with the curriculum of the course of study.

Your employer must obtain approval for the internship from the Employment Agency: https://www3.arbeitsagentur.de/web/wcm/idc/groups/public/documents/webdatei/mdaw/mdc4/~edisp/l6019022dstbai381815.pdf?_ba.sid=L6019022DSTBAI381818 I would therefore recommend that the university in Germany send the documents listed on page 3 of the link by e-mail to the relevant department:

Agentur für Arbeit Köln 
Team 008 (Standort Bonn)
Villemombler Straße 76
53123 Bonn 
 E-Mail: Koeln.Studenten@arbeitsagentur.de 
Faxnummer: 0228 713-1037

The answer is then important for you and must be submitted with your application to the German Embassy.